# Estoy haciendo un conversor de binario a decimal i al revés con javascript, y quiero que en el <input> del numero binario sólo acepte 1 y 0

Tags: javascript, html

de momento tengo esto:

JS:

```
var input_binary = document.getElementById('input_conversor_binary');
        var input_decimal = document.getElementById('input_conversor_decimal');
```

HTML:

```
<input id="input_conversor_binary" type="text">
<input id="input_conversor_decimal" type="text">
```

Comment: Con HTML5 puedes usar un patrón para validar el elemento input. Con el atributo [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) junto con una expresión regular que permita sólo valores binarios, como por ejemplo: `[0-1]+`. De esta forma muestras visualmente al usuario que no ha introducido valores válidos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes capturar el valor de tu input `input_binary` y luego reemplazar todos los caracteres que no sean `0` o `1` por una cadena vacía, utilizando una expresión regular, por ejemplo:

```js
let input_binary = document.getElementById('input_conversor_binary');
let input_decimal = document.getElementById('input_conversor_decimal');

input_binary.addEventListener('input', function() {
  let inputValue = input_binary.value;
  let newValue = inputValue.replace(/[^01]/g, '');
  input_binary.value = newValue;
});
```

```html
<input id="input_conversor_binary" type="text">
<input id="input_conversor_decimal" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias crear una función en JS que valide esa entrada, algo asi:

HTML:

```
<input id="input_conversor_binary" type="text" oninput="validateBinaryInput(this)">
<input id="input_conversor_decimal" type="text">
```

JS:

```
function validateBinaryInput(input) {
// Elimina cualquier carácter que no sea '0' o '1'
input.value = input.value.replace(/[^01]/g, '');
}
```